# Time with PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL. Now I'm trying to get the date and time in MySQL. But without succes, I already been trying it for a couple of days :-(

The error message:

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax.

In MySQL I have given the variable timechoice the type 'DATETIME'. Is there the mistake or is it in my code? THANKS!

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $choice = $_POST["choice"];
    $today = date("y-m-d h:m:s");


$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE Deelnemers SET choice='$choice' timechoice='$today' WHERE teamnaam='".$_SESSION['username']."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo 'antwoord verwerkt';
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: Because no one has mentioned it yet, your query is vulnerable to injection attack. Look at the [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) method and implement it before you run this code live somewhere.

Comment: Make a debug output of the contents of `$sql` as well, so that you can check the syntax of what you have assembled there.

Comment: *Ouch!* - This just screams **inject me!**

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I have to learn that part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, try using this query,

```
UPDATE Deelnemers SET choice='$choice',timechoice='$today' WHERE teamnaam='".$_SESSION['username']."';
```

Also, as you have mentioned you have this error,

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax.
>
> In MySQL I have given the variable timechoice the type 'DATETIME'. Is
>   there the mistake or is it in my code? THANKS!

Answer to this is, eitheir the field $today is not proper, if you have given `DATETIME` datatype in mysql then try this

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

*P.S - I don't recommend you to use this,as your code is vulnerable.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get closer and closer but I'm not there yet. 

There was a comment who said I had to change timechoice to = '.$today.' That worked, no error message anymore. But MySQL still gives 0000-00-00 00:00:00 :-(

$choice still works!

Comment: so that is the reason why replace $today with the line I have given and try,it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong,

```
$sql = "UPDATE Deelnemers SET choice = '$choice', timechoice = '$today' WHERE teamnaam = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Notice the commas after `'$choice'`.

I'd also point out several comments under your question in regards to SQL injection issues. These are important observations in ensuring DB security and handling user input.

Comment: quotes actually not needed, `,` required in between

Comment: Even for the 'timechoice' column?

Comment: yes,`""` interpret variables correctly so `''` around all variable will work perfectly.